# Setting Multiple Variables with php and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a code I want to use

```
mysql_select_db("website", $con);
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM characters where online='1'");
    while ($row=
                mysql_fetch_array($result))
                {
                echo $row['name'];
                }
                if ($row['race'] == "1");
                {
                echo '<img src="img/8-0.gif" />';
                }
                if ($row['class'] == "3");
                {
                echo '<img src="img/3.gif" ?>';
                }
            mysql_close($con);
        ?>
```

Now I only wanted the two images to show if the online field was 1, but they show no matter what. Does anyone know how I can fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Seriously, what have you tried? You do know about data types in mysql? use `online=1` instead of `online='1'`.

Comment: Add if ([is online?]) echo <img ... ?

Comment: @fdomig Though it's not my place to say, what if the type is actually 'VARCHAR', instead of 'int'? I know, it would make no sense at all, but in that case, not checking for literal may well go wrong.

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of the argument:

```
mysql_select_db("website", $con);
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM characters where online='1'");
while ($row= mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row['name'];
//} This bracket would immediately close your query processing and only display the last images. Or is that the desired behaviour?
    if($row['isOnline'] == '1') { //Makes sure, that 'isOnline' is set before displaying.
            if ($row['race'] == "1");
            {
            echo '<img src="img/8-0.gif" />';
            }
            if ($row['class'] == "3");
            {
            echo '<img src="img/3.gif" ?>';
            }
    }
} //This bracket closes the actual query result handling
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            if ($row['race'] == "1" AND $row['online'] == 1);
            {
            echo '<img src="img/8-0.gif" />';
            }
            if ($row['class'] == "3" AND $row['online'] == 1);
            {
            echo '<img src="img/3.gif" ?>';
            }
```